# What did Eisenhower mean with this statement?

Tags: united-states, president, history, reference-request

> “They are very volatile. They think they are a great power one day and they feel sorry for themselves the next day.”

This quote above is from [this article in _The New Yorker](https://www.newyorker.com/news/daily-comment/eisenhower-1954-obama-2013).
But what does this mean?

Comment: I would point out (with respect to the article) that at the time (1954) Vietnam was a french territory.  So the attacks were an attack on a US Ally.  This is quite different from Syria.

Comment: For future reference, the article in question is located [here](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/comment/2013/09/obama-syria-decision-remembering-eisenhower-and-vietnam.html).

Comment: A lot more context is needed around that quote. Without spending time to read the article on an external site we have no reference to what that quote is about.

Answer (score 3):

The quote you posted seemed to be directed toward France,

And it appears to mean that France believes themselves to be more powerful than they actually are, and this sentiment might come from the fact that France was taken by Germany fairly early in WWII

Comment: @AndySmith that's what it seems to mean